# Is it possible to debug apache nifi custom processor?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-nifi

I am able to remote debug apache nifi custom processor in eclipse (ref:[1](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/106931/nifi-debugging-tutorial.html),[2](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/sdk-debug-eclipse.html),[3](https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-remote-debug-with-eclipse/)). The steps I follow are something like this:

1. Uncomment below line in apache nifi bootstrap.conf

   ```
   java.arg.debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
   ```
2. Start apache nifi
3. Create new debug configuration in eclipse with `host=localhost`,`port=8000` and select custom processor's project.

So I am able to hover the variables, add watch and do step through etc. However, once I get some hint and want to change some code and quickly try, what can be done? Do I need to change code, rebuild nar, stop apache nifi, put nar in apache nifi lib and then restart apache nifi. Do I have to follow this long path every time I do some code changes? Or I am missing something? I tried by changing code and saving it. But the moment I do Ctrl+S, it shows me unable to hot swap code changes screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to rebuild and redeploy the NAR as you described. Generally you shouldn't have to debug too often because you should be developing the processor using a unit test built with NiFi's mock testing framework and you will have a pretty good idea the processor is going to work before ever running it. Then remote debugging is only really needed for unusual cases that can't be simulated in a unit test.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can debug Custom Nifi Processor. Code your custom processor with any code editor, create nar file and copy that nar file to lib directory where your NiFi set-up is there.

Go to the conf directory inside your NiFi set-up and search for the file bootstrap.conf.

Open bootstrap.conf file in any available editor and uncomment the below line

**java.arg.debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000**

Your can change the port availability as per your system.

Now move into your code editor(IntelliJ here) and open the drop down 'Edit Run/Debug Configurations dialog' on the top right side beside the hammer symbol.

Click on Edit configurations option

Below windows open up

[image]

Click on plus sign(+) on top left, a drop down will appear, select the remote

[image]

Below screen appears

[image]

Configure your port that you have mentioned in bootstrap.conf file in NiFi, suppose we have configured 8000 then we need to change the port to 8000

[image]

click on Apply and then OK button

Now place the debug points on the custom class that you have written and then click on debug icon on Nifi on the top right side

[image]

You will see the console like below

[image]

Now open your Nifi on browser of your choice and then start your custom processor (on browser) and then as soon as your processor starts running, debug point on the IntelliJ will hit and you can start debugging your custom processor

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Don't forget to restart Nifi after changing the bootstrap.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bryan's answer, you can use the `ExecuteScript` processor with Groovy (you can write pure Java if you wish) to cut down this "live testing" feedback cycle. You:

1. write code directly in the body of the processor
2. run the processor
3. evaluate the success
4. stop the processor
5. modify code
6. start it again

Repeat this cycle until you have code you are reasonably happy with, and then translate it to the custom processor. As Bryan notes, your unit tests should cover the internal behavior pretty well, but this will reduce the deployment time between cycles.

I have done a [presentation on custom processor development](https://github.com/alopresto/slides/tree/master/dws_barcelona_2019) which may help as well.